# How to solve the "Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.StackOverflowError" ? in my Application

Tags: java, multithreading, stack-overflow

In my application i am accessing data from another system Database through ip address communication.

So for that,if database system is offline at that time exception is occur during connection so in catch block again i am calling run() method ,when it come to online normal flow of application execution happen. but in this process i am getting "Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.StackOverflowError" this exception how to solve this exception in my scenario.

This is my code:

```
MAIN CLASS :-

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new LsduJFrame().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
 new Thread(new DisplayPlazaNameLocation()).start();// i am calling here
}

DisplayPlazaNameLocation:-

public class DisplayPlazaNameLocation implements Runnable{
static String plazaNameLocation;
static Connection con;
int i =0;
public  void getPlazaNameLocation(){
    try {
        System.out.println("in getPlazaNameLocation()==============================================");
        PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT Plaza_Loc FROM lsdu_live");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            plazaNameLocation = rs.getString("Plaza_Loc");
            //System.out.println(plazaNameLocation);
        }

        String ar[] = plazaNameLocation.split(",");
        jLabel199.setText("<html>"+ar[0]+"<br>"+ar[1]+"</html>");
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        run();
     }
}
 @Override
public void run(){
    try {
        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER_CLASS);
        con= DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL[0],DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
       if(con != null){
        this.getPlazaNameLocation();}
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
         run();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        run();
    }

}
```

}

After executing some time I am getting this exception `Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.StackOverflowError`

suppose when i resolve the Connection issue before getting this Exception the application working fine, but after getting this exception, no use of resolve after getting this exception at that time i need close the application and open again at that time it's working. `How to resolve this issue with respect to my code ?`

```
stackTrace() data:-

Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:66)
at java.sql.SQLException.<init>(SQLException.java:70)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at lsdu_application.DisplayPlazaNameLocation.run(DisplayPlazaNameLocation.java:47)
at lsdu_application.DisplayPlazaNameLocation.run(DisplayPlazaNameLocation.java:59)
at
```

Comment: Could you attach the stack trace?

Comment: Add the full stacktrace.

Comment: If you encouter an exception, you just call `run()` again. What do you expect to happen the 2nd, 3rd or 5000th time around? It won't automatically start working if you just retry long enough.

Answer (score 5):

In your `run` method, you call `getPlazaNameLocation`. If the SQL fails, you call `run` again. This causes an infinite "loop" (recursion) between those 2 methods, each call adding onto your call stack which eventually causes a `StackOverflowError`.

- why do you call `run` in case of an SQLException? You should handle the error in the catch block, not restart your functionality. Remove that call and get some infos about your `SQLException` using `e.printStackTrace()`.
- never call `run` manually. That is supposed to be invoked using `Thread.start()`.

EDIT: If you really want to re-try the database operation in case it fails, try this:

```
public void getPlazaNameLocation() throws SQLException {
  //same code, but remove the try/catch blocks and
  // especially the run()!
}

@Override
public void run(){
  try {
    Class.forName(DB_DRIVER_CLASS);
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL[0],DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    //fail here since no driver was found
    return;
  }

  boolean retry = true;
  while(retry){
    try {
      getPlazaNameLocation();
      retry = false;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
      //if we arrive here, "retry" will still have a value of true
    }
  }
}
```

Please note i don't recommend spamming requests over a broken connection to the database like this code does.

Comment: I am little bit late :)

Comment: Thanks for giving reply :-initial connection ok in run(), after that i am calling getPlazaNameLocation() method at that time is there any connection issue with network to access the db of other system at that time in catch block again i am calling run() for re-connection. instead of that how can i do this process -@ f1sh

Comment: @f1sh - Thanks for giving Reply, but when i tried your code "return " is not calling connection again , where "return" call will go .

Comment: @f1sh -catch (SQLException ex) {
        //fail at con = DriverManager line jvm comes to here
        return;
    } here return calls which code.